# Microsoft Azure Rest API Using Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage-emulator, azure-emulator

I want to build a Rest API in Java to communicate with Azure Storage Service.

I found that I can use Azure Storage Emulator (however there is drawback to it as it has different addressing etc. as compared to online service) without going in pain with subscription and providing my Card Details which proved fatal for me when I did for Amazon.

The problem I am facing is I am not able to find any tutorial on how to use Eclipse IDE in conjunction with Storage Emulator. OR is there any other IDE like Android Studio which has built in Emulator.

I am trying to build a simple API through which I can use Blob service to upload pictures from my local folder to Amazon Storage.

Please guide me or specify brief steps to do this task, I know there are many different tutorial regarding this on MSDN but that is causing me all the doubts as I am not able to decide what to follow. And I don't want to use the Web APP provided by Microsoft. I want to build my own Java API.

Comment: Just thinking, will Google Drive help?

Comment: Why can't you use Java SDK for Azure Storage?

Comment: Hi @GauravMantri mere coincidence I was actually reading one of your post only. Really liked your posts.  Gaurav I want to built from scratch don't want to use a library. However, can we use SDK in conjunction with Emulator or I have to make an online account.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you liked my posts :). Coming to your question, I think there should be only 2 reasons for going down "Do It Yourself" route: 1) There's no SDK available and 2) SDK is not kept uptodate. When it comes to Azure Storage, both of them are not true. Storage team is quite particular about this. New versions SDKs are released with the latest changes in the REST API. Furthermore, I believe that using the SDK will make you more productive in the sense that most of the work has already been done by the SDK and you can focus on your application. HTH.

Comment: SDK does support Emulator. You don't have to create a cloud storage account. But there are some differences between emulator and actual cloud storage account. So please take those into consideration.

Comment: @ArjunChaudhary Using Azure Storage Emulator via connection string is supported in SDK. To know the difference of connection string between emulator and online, please refer to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-configure-connection-string). Or you can use emulator in SDK via the code `CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.getDevelopmentStorageAccount()` instead of parsing connection string for emulator.